# Pandas Calculate Logical OR based on several columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is a `DataFrame` I am working on:

```
{'Recipe@123': ['AAA', nan, nan],
 'Recipe@234': [nan, 'BBB', nan],
 'Recipe@456': [nan, nan, 'CCC'],
'Operation@123':[1,nan,nan],
'Operation@234':[nan,2,nan],
'Operation@456':[nan,nan, 3]
}
```

I am trying to create a `Recipe` column that will include not `NaN` recipe based on row values.
For instance 1st row value will be `AAA`, 2nd - `BBB` , etc. There are additional columns in DF, but `Recipe` column should take into account only 3 mentioned.

Comment: So there's always just one non-nan value in each row, and you want that value in the new column?

Comment: that is correct. Thank you

Comment: You could just do `df.max()` for this example, but you may be looking for a more general solution.

Comment: can you please write a code?

Comment: That's the code. Type `df.max()` and you'll get a Series with the result you're looking for.

Comment: assuming we have additional columns in DF and value calculated only based on these 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` to apply for rows with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) method, if you have only one valid value and all other are `NaN` (using @Stefan example):

```
In [197]: df
Out[197]: 
  Recipe@123 Recipe@234 Recipe@456  other_col
0        AAA        NaN        NaN          1
1        NaN        BBB        NaN          2
2        NaN        NaN        CCC          3

In [199]: df['new'] = df[['Recipe@123', 'Recipe@234', 'Recipe@456']].apply(lambda x: x.any(), axis=1)

In [200]: df
Out[200]: 
  Recipe@123 Recipe@234 Recipe@456  other_col  new
0        AAA        NaN        NaN          1  AAA
1        NaN        BBB        NaN          2  BBB
2        NaN        NaN        CCC          3  CCC
```

**EDIT**

It's a seems a bit like a hack but I think that should work (calling `min` if `dtype` is numeric alternatively `any`):

```
 df['new'] = df[['Operation@123', 'Operation@234', 'Operation@456']].apply(lambda x: x.min() if x.dtype.kind in 'biufc' else x.any(), axis=1)

In [551]: df
Out[551]: 
   Operation@123  Operation@234  Operation@456 Recipe@123 Recipe@234  \
0              1            NaN            NaN        AAA        NaN   
1            NaN              2            NaN        NaN        BBB   
2            NaN            NaN              3        NaN        NaN   

  Recipe@456  new  
0        NaN    1  
1        NaN    2  
2        CCC    3
```

*Note*: [`dtype.kind`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html)

Comment: Thank you, Anton. Works perfect.

Comment: Anton, This solution works fine with strings. With numerical values it isn't robust. What need to be changed in your solution that will be possible to extract only numerical value from row values? Thank you

Comment: Could you show appropriate example? You could convert everything to string with `astype(str)` but it's not a good way...

Comment: what output should be for that example? I've got `'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'`. Is it wrong?

Comment: Should be '1', '2','3' for each row respectively

Comment: Spasibo, Anton. works perfect. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99030/discussion-between-felix-and-anton-protopopov).

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Recipe@123': ['AAA', np.nan, np.nan], 'Recipe@234': [np.nan, 'BBB', np.nan], 'Recipe@456': [np.nan, np.nan, 'CCC'], 'other_col': [1, 2, 3]})

  Recipe@123 Recipe@234 Recipe@456  other_col
0        AAA        NaN        NaN          1
1        NaN        BBB        NaN          2
2        NaN        NaN        CCC          3
```

just iterate through the `rows` and use `.dropna` to get rid of the missing values, which you can write to a new `DataFrame` column like so:

```
for i, data in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'Recipe'] = data[['Recipe@123', 'Recipe@234', 'Recipe@456']].dropna().values[0]

  Recipe@123 Recipe@234 Recipe@456  other_col Recipe
0        AAA        NaN        NaN          1    AAA
1        NaN        BBB        NaN          2    BBB
2        NaN        NaN        CCC          3    CCC
```

Comment: Thank you, Stefan, but this seems not working. I would like to get Recipe column as DF column

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Works for me with `pandas 0.17.1`.

Comment: DF doesn't have Recipe column. Data frame still need contain 'Recipe@123', 'Recipe@234' and 'Recipe@456'

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. This is working. In case DF has additional columns, how code will looks if i would like to refer to only 3 specific columns i mentioned? Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98994/discussion-between-felix-and-stefan).